# How to get line break in JLatexMathView

Tags: java, android

I have created an app in which I will provide maths and physics questions which will include formula and text both. I am showing these questions in JLatexMathView so that formula can be displayed properly. But this view is showing the whole question no matter how many words are there in it , in just one line. When the number of words is increasing it decreases the size of the word but adjust the whole question in one line. I want to show it in paragraph form. How can I do that ?

XML code

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ru.noties.jlatexmath.JLatexMathView
        android:id="@+id/j_latex_math_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="16dip"
        app:jlmv_alignHorizontal="center"
        app:jlmv_alignVertical="center"
        app:jlmv_textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```


JAVA code
````

final JLatexMathDrawable drawable = JLatexMathDrawable.builder("\text{let find the formula find the formula and solve          " +
" it now \n $56 \times 89 \overleftarrow{} \prod \; \lim_{n \to \infty} \coprod$}")
.textSize(70)
.padding(8)
.background(0xFFffffff)
.align(JLatexMathDrawable.ALIGN_RIGHT)
.build();

```
    latex.setLatexDrawable(drawable);
```

```
I was trying to show the question using jLatexMathView as a paragraph but it is being shown as a single line
```